# How to make my HTML comments look like this?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am trying to make my HTML comment tags look like arrows instead of the usual <!-- and color them without coloring the whole comment like this in vs-code:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZTFJ.png)

I tried looking it up but all i found was how to change the font and color of the comment as a whole which is not what i am looking for, i just want the tags to be arrows and colored

Comment: You can't change comment tags - they are just part of the source and don't get rendered on the page.  If you are talking about how it looks in your editor, then maybe your editor will have some settings

Comment: yea i mean in vs code, i tried to find the settings for it but couldn't find anything

Comment: I don't think you can change `<!--` - it's a html standard so if you used anything else, the browser wouldn't know it's a comment.   Not sure why you need so many comments though - you're just adding bloat, do you really need to comment that a meta description tag is the meta description?

Comment: install a font with **Font Ligatures** (Fira Code) and enable Font Ligatures in VSC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining a sequence of characters into something that looks like a single character is called a [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)).

You need to:

- Enable them in VS Code (Open the settings and search for the keyword `fontLigatures`, then set it to `true`)
- Use a font that supports the particular ligatures you want to use ([select the font](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=programmer+fonts+that+support+ligatures&t=h_&ia=web), install it, then specify it with the `fontFamily` setting).